# Meteor module not found on prod, works fine in dev

Tags: heroku, meteor, flow-router

I've recently been adding flow router to my meteor project. Works fine in dev, I deploy on my dev server, a heroku dyno [using horse buildpack](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse).
And surprise, my app doesn't work, the js console logs an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find package "kadira:flow-router". Try "meteor add kadira:flow-router".
```

I've added the module to meteor by doing this:

```
meteor add kadira:flow-router
```

I'm my route.jsx is in /client/route/route.jsx

```
import { FlowRouter }  from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
```

I don't get why my dev/prod are not the same. Any hint ?
I didn't find any error in the deployment logs on heroku
I also realized something, when heroku builds the prod, it seems to be using Meteor 1.8.1 while I've updated my meteor version to the last 1.10.smthg. How does that happen ? Is it linked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the answer: somehow my adding packages and updating meteor on my dev wasn't being committed to my git repo. Hence, not to the heroku dyno.

I'm not sure what's the issue on how I use git, .meteor is not in the git ignore